Image button command inside nested Grids is not triggered
I have a collectionview binding to a list of records.
I have nested grid below the above list to display paging controls used to navigate to different pages of the records.
The pagination controls inside the nested grid are not triggered when the imageButtons are clicked.
I also have commands outside the nested grid and they trigger the viewmodel events.
I am using
Command="{Binding BindingContext.FirstCommand, Source={x:Reference ParentGrid}}"  

where parentGrid is the name of the Parent Grid.
What am I missing here?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Matri.Views.AllProfilesPage"
             xmlns:FoA="clr-namespace:Matri.FontsAwesome;assembly=Matri"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             Title="All Profiles" BackgroundColor="White">
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"></ActivityIndicator>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="{Binding ShowRecordsNotFoundSection}">
                <Label FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Records not found."></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" IsVisible="{Binding ShowRecordsSection}">
                <CollectionView x:Name="profilesCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" 
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SelectionMode="Single" 
                            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ViewProfileCommand}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile}"
                            SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source={x:Reference profilesCollectionView}}"
                            >
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="94"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Frame HorizontalOptions="Center" IsClippedToBounds="True" CornerRadius="4" HasShadow="False" Grid.Row="0" 
                                   Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="72" WidthRequest="72" Padding="0">
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       HeightRequest="72" WidthRequest="72" 
                                       Aspect="Fill">
                                        <Image.Source>
                                            <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ThumbNailUri}"/>
                                        </Image.Source>
                                    </Image>
                                </Frame>
                                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
                                       TextColor="#DE000000" FontFamily="Roboto-Medium" 
                                       FontSize="{OnPlatform Android={OnIdiom Phone=15, Tablet=22}, iOS=16, WinUI=14,MacCatalyst=16}" 
                                       CharacterSpacing="0.1" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                                    <!--<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="1w ago" TextColor="#666666" 
                                       FontSize="{OnPlatform Default=10,WinUI=12,MacCatalyst=12}" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="End" CharacterSpacing="0.15" Margin="0,10,11,0"/>-->
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="#666666" 
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform iOS={OnIdiom Tablet=1.2, Default=1.025}, Default=1.2}" 
                                       Text="{Binding Height}" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="14" CharacterSpacing="0.1" 
                                       Margin="0,4,0,0" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="#666666" 
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform iOS={OnIdiom Tablet=1.2, Default=1.025}, Default=1.2}" 
                                       Text="{Binding Age}" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="14" CharacterSpacing="0.1" 
                                       Margin="0,4,0,0" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="#666666" 
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform iOS={OnIdiom Tablet=1.2, Default=1.025}, Default=1.2}" 
                                       Text="{Binding Education}" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="14" CharacterSpacing="0.1" 
                                       Margin="0,4,0,0" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor="#666666" 
                                       LineHeight="{OnPlatform iOS={OnIdiom Tablet=1.2, Default=1.025}, Default=1.2}" 
                                       Text="{Binding Job}" FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" FontSize="14" CharacterSpacing="0.1" 
                                       Margin="0,4,0,10" />
                                </Grid>
                                <BoxView Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="1" 
                                     VerticalOptions="End" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
                <!--<Frame Margin="0,5,0,0" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Padding="10">-->
                    <Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,18,0,15">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ImageButton Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
HeightRequest="25" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="First"
Command="{Binding BindingContext.FirstCommand, Source={x:Reference ParentGrid}}"                                         
                                         HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="25" >
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid"
     Glyph="{x:Static FoA:FontAwesomeIcons.AngleDoubleLeft}" Color="Gray" />
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>

                            <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Start" Aspect="AspectFill"
HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                          Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid"
                             Glyph="{x:Static FoA:FontAwesomeIcons.AngleLeft}" Color="Gray" />
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>

                            <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="End" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" VerticalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding NextCommand}">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource
                     FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid"
                     Glyph="{x:Static FoA:FontAwesomeIcons.AngleRight}"
                     Color="Gray" />
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>

                            <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="End" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"
HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="Last"
                                         Command="{Binding LastCommand}">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource
                     FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid"
                     Glyph="{x:Static FoA:FontAwesomeIcons.AngleDoubleRight}"
                     Color="gray" />
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                        </Grid>

                        <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="Small" Grid.Column="0" Text="Profiles Per Page" 
                               VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Start"></Label>
                        <Picker x:Name="PickerPageSize" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding PageSizeList}"  HorizontalOptions="Start"
                     ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}" SelectedItem="{Binding PPageSize}" >
                            <Picker.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                     EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
                                     Command="{Binding SelectedPageSizeCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{ Binding .}" />
                            </Picker.Behaviors>
                        </Picker>

                        <Label Grid.Row="2" FontSize="Small" Grid.Column="0" Text="Current Page"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" Text="{Binding EPageNumber}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="2" 
                               Grid.Column="2" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" 
                               Text="{Binding LNumberOfPages}" />

                    </Grid>
                <!--</Frame>-->
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>




using Matri.ViewModel;

namespace Matri.Views;

public partial class AllProfilesPage : ContentPage
{
    public AllProfilesPage(AllProfilesViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}



[RelayCommand]
private async Task Next()
{
    int ePN = Convert.ToInt32(EPageNumber);
    if (ePN < totalPages)
    {
        ePN = ePN + 1;
        await GetProfiles(ePN, Convert.ToInt16(PPageSize.Value));
        EPageNumber = ePN.ToString();
    }
}



using Matri.Business;
using Matri.CustomExceptions;
using Matri.Model;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MvvmHelpers;
using Matri.Helper;

namespace Matri.ViewModel
{
    public partial class AllProfilesViewModel : CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject
    {
        IServiceManager _serviceManager;

        public static int totalPages;
        public Guid LoggedInId = new Guid();

        public AllProfilesViewModel(IServiceManager serviceManager)
        {
            _serviceManager = serviceManager;
            PageSizeList.Add(new PageSize { Text = "10", Value = 10 });
            PageSizeList.Add(new PageSize { Text = "20", Value = 20 });
            PageSizeList.Add(new PageSize { Text = "50", Value = 50 });
            pPageSize = PageSizeList[0];
            Task.Run(() => this.GetProfiles(1, pPageSize.Value));
        }
        public ObservableRangeCollection<PageSize> PageSizeList { get; private set; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<PageSize>();

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string ePageNumber;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public PageSize pPageSize;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string lNumberOfPages;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public MiniProfile selectedProfile;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool showRecordsSection;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool showRecordsNotFoundSection;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public bool isBusy = true;

        public ObservableRangeCollection<MiniProfile> Profiles { get; private set; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<MiniProfile>();

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Cancel()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///LandingPage");
        }

        public async Task<bool> GetProfiles(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var token = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Token");
            try
            {
                Profiles.Clear();

                var dbProfilesWithPaging = await _serviceManager.GetProfiles(new Guid(token), pageNumber, pageSize);
                var dbProfiles = dbProfilesWithPaging.Data;
                var modValue = dbProfilesWithPaging.MetaData.TotalRecords % pageSize;

                totalPages = dbProfilesWithPaging.MetaData.TotalRecords / pageSize;
                if (modValue != 0)
                {
                    totalPages += 1;
                }
                LNumberOfPages = $"/{totalPages}";
                EPageNumber = pageNumber.ToString();

                Profiles.AddRange(dbProfiles);

                if (dbProfilesWithPaging.MetaData.TotalRecords == 0)
                {
                    ShowRecordsNotFoundSection = true;
                    ShowRecordsSection = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ShowRecordsNotFoundSection = false;
                    ShowRecordsSection = true;
                }
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            catch (MatriInternetException exception)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task Previous()
        {
            int ePN = Convert.ToInt32(EPageNumber);
            if (ePN >= 2 && ePN <= totalPages)
            {
                ePN = ePN - 1;
                await GetProfiles(ePN, Convert.ToInt16(PPageSize.Value));
                EPageNumber = ePN.ToString();
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task Next()
        {
            int ePN = Convert.ToInt32(EPageNumber);
            if (ePN < totalPages)
            {
                ePN = ePN + 1;
                await GetProfiles(ePN, Convert.ToInt16(PPageSize.Value));
                EPageNumber = ePN.ToString();
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task First()
        {
            await GetProfiles(1, Convert.ToInt16(PPageSize.Value));
            EPageNumber = "1";
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task Last()
        {
            int ePN = totalPages;
            await GetProfiles(ePN, Convert.ToInt16(PPageSize.Value));
            EPageNumber = ePN.ToString();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task GoToPage()
        {
            int ePN = Convert.ToInt32(EPageNumber);
            if (ePN != 0 && ePN <= totalPages)
            {
                await GetProfiles(ePN, Convert.ToInt16(PPageSize.Value));
                EPageNumber = ePN.ToString();
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task SelectedPageSize(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj != null && obj is AllProfilesViewModel)
            {
                var item = (AllProfilesViewModel)obj;

                int index = PageSizeList.ToList().FindIndex(a => a.Value == item.PPageSize.Value);
                PPageSize = PageSizeList[index];

                await GetProfiles(Convert.ToInt32(EPageNumber), Convert.ToInt16(item.PPageSize.Value));
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task ViewProfile(Object obj)
        {

            IsBusy = true;
            if (obj != null && obj is MiniProfile)
            {
                var item = (MiniProfile)obj;

                var sessionToken = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Token");
                var targetProfileId = item.Id;

                //log the current user as visitor for the tapped profile
                await _serviceManager.CreateProfileVisitor(new Guid(sessionToken), targetProfileId);

                var allRequests = await _serviceManager.GetAllRequests(new Guid(sessionToken));
                var requestsSentToSelectedUser = allRequests.Where(ar => ar.ReceiverId == targetProfileId).ToList();

                var profileDetailsInput = ServiceHelper.InitialiseRequestsSent(requestsSentToSelectedUser);

                profileDetailsInput.LoggedInId = new Guid(sessionToken);
                profileDetailsInput.TargetProfileId = targetProfileId;

                var profileDetailsParams = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "ProfileDetailsInput", profileDetailsInput } };
                IsBusy = false;
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("profiledetails", profileDetailsParams);
            }
        }
    }
}


Could you please post the code of AllProfilesViewModel.cs so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Hi Jessie, I have posted the AllProfilesViewModel

I think the issue is here could be with styling. You have pretty complex UI with nested Grid's. On top of that you are using ImageButton. Try to add BackgroundColor to image buttons. This will reveal the actual position of image button in the view. There is chance that Image of image button can be arranged improperly in the view.
You can also check setting the ImageButton's Source normally and  still the issue persists or not ...Source="image.png"

I could reproduce this problem.
When I tried to set property BackgroundColor for the Grid occupied by these buttons(e.g. BackgroundColor="Pink"), I noticed that the background is not displayed. Then I found out that you have set the margin of the Grid in this row to Margin="0,18,0,15", then the sum of the upper and lower margins of this row is larger than the Row height you set(<RowDefinition Height="30"/>), which is unreasonable. When I tried to set the row height to a larger value(e.g. <RowDefinition Height="60"/>), the background color of the row is displayed, and the buttons in this row also trigger click events as expected.
You can refer to the following code:
            <Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,18,0,15" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- For the sake of simplicity, the other codes are omitted  -->

            </Grid>


That did the work. Thank you for explaining why its not working, how to debug the issue and suggesting a fix.

Hi  @sham, my answer is my step-by-step process of figuring out the problem. As mentioned above, the solution is to raise the height of this line(e.g. <RowDefinition Height="60"/>).
